# Does text overflow a Google Spreadsheet cell if the cell next to it is empty?

Tags: google-sheets

In Microsoft Office Excel a long text string is readable over multiple columns whenever the next (right) column is empty. Is that also possible within Google Spreadsheet?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you do not want your text to overflow use **Format** > **Text wrapping** > **Clip**. This will work even if the next cell is empty.

Comment: I came here searching for this answer, thank you!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The actual accepted answer doesn't provide any useful information at all.

Comment: Some kind of contents won't follow the overflow rule. For example if there is an implicit formatting, like dates, currencies...

Answer (score 5):

That's only possible when you're using the new Google Spreadsheet:

[image: screen shot without text in adjacent column]

and now with text in column B:

[image: screen shot with text in adjacent column]

Read all about the new Google Spreadsheet in [this official blog](http://googleblog.blogspot.nl/2013/12/new-google-sheets-faster-more-powerful.html)

Comment: It would be much appreciated if this feature could be turned off. It clutters up the display if you optionally have text in the column to the right.

Comment: Did you test @black_falco answer? I don't know back then, but now it works for me.

Comment: This answer is outdated. Hiding overflow can now be performed, cf Quentin Caron's answer

Answer (score 2):

If  Format - Text wrapping - Clip isn't resolving your issue, try:

**Select All** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>
to **Clear Formatting**.

Can be also done from the **Format menu** (at the top), choose the last Option, **Clear Formatting**.

Answer (score -1):

This problem can also arise if there is some clever cell merging - as is often the case if using templates. Either select the existing cells and adjacent one doing the cut-off and Format-MergeCells-.. or unmerge them (or use tool at the top of page)